# Media Queries Between Widths

Tags: css, media-queries

I'd like to change the padding-left to 24px between 769px and 1340px, but my current media query is not working. Looking to resolve this issue.

```
@media(min-width:1340px){
    .target-side-col li{
        padding-left:60px;
    }
}

@media(min-width:769px && max-width:1340px){
    .target-side-col li{
        padding-left:24px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct syntax is :

```
 @media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1340px) {
         .target-side-col li{
                padding-left:24px;
          }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this syntax.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1340px) and (min-width: 769px) {
.target-side-col li{
 padding-left:24px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to use media query is as follows.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1340px) {
your style here
}
```